# control schema file name created by jaxb schemagen maven plugin (maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin)

Tags: java, maven-2, jaxb, schemagen

I don't seem to be able to work out how to get control the file name of the XSD file created by maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin. The [documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/maven-jaxb-schemagen/generate-mojo.html) is a bit sparse.

```
        <groupId>com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <project>${project}</project>
           <destdir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/schemas</destdir>
           <srcdir>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/my/jaxb/bean/package</srcdir>
           <verbose>true</verbose>
        </configuration>
```

It always seems to create a file called schema1.xsd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add schema elements which describe which file should contain the elements of each namespace you have:

```
<configuration>
    [...]
    <schemas>
       <schema>
          <namespace>http://www.example.invalid/2001/05/27/wibble</namespace>
          <file>wibble.xsd</file>
       </schema>
    </schemas>
<configuration>
```

Assuming you have set the namespace of you components

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "wobble", namespace="http://www.example.invalid/2001/05/27/wibble")
```

Comment: The namespace can be specified at package level, or using `@XmlType` annotations for classes as well. Also, this doesn't seem possible to do using command line schemagen.