# jaxb2-maven-plugin not renaming xmls and generated xsd doesnt contain namespace

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate xsd out of java objects that are annotated with jaxb annotations. When executing the `schemagen` its generating xsd but it doesnt rename it and no namespace exists.
During maven install execution, I see an warning from the plugin

```
[INFO] XSD post-processing: Renaming and converting XSDs.
[WARNING] SimpleNamespaceResolver contained no localNamespaceURI; aborting rename.
```

while debugging the jaxb2-maven plugin code, its trying to search namespace in the generated xml and I dont see that either. So namespace given in java classes are not translating to XSDs.
Here is pom.xml and java classes and generated xsds for reference

I have looked into couple of posts before posting question,  but none of the solutions work.

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150884/control-schema-file-name-created-by-jaxb-schemagen-maven-plugin-maven-jaxb-sche) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281636/how-to-predefine-xsd-file-name-with-jaxb2-maven-plugin) [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810904/validation-of-xml-with-maven-created-schema-fails-when-namespace-is-defined)

pom.xml

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schemagen</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>schemagen</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        ${project.basedir}\src\main\java\com\example\o\tools\overridesscanner\xsd\beans\</source>
                </sources>
                <quiet>true</quiet>
                <sources>
                    <source>
                        ${project.basedir}\src\main\java\com\example\o\tools\overridesscanner\xsd\beans\Release.java</source>
                    <source>
                        ${project.basedir}\src\main\java\com\example\o\tools\overridesscanner\xsd\beans\Root.java</source>
                </sources>
                <transformSchemas>
                    <transformSchema>
                        <uri>http://www.example.com/2023/08/31/releases</uri>
                        <toPrefix>some</toPrefix>
                        <toFile>some_schema.xsd</toFile>
                    </transformSchema>
                </transformSchemas>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}\src\main\resources\schemas</outputDirectory>
                <clearOutputDir>true</clearOutputDir>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Generated xsd with name schema1.xsd

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">

    <xs:complexType name="release">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parentReleaseName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="parentReleasePath" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="releaseName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="root">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="releases" nillable="true"
                type="release" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Classes annotated with jaxb annotations

package-info.java

```java
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.com/2023/08/31/releases")
package com.example.o.tools.overridesscanner.xsd.beans;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Root.java

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "root", namespace = "http://www.example.com/2023/08/31/releases")
@XmlType(namespace = "http://www.example.com/2023/08/31/releases")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    public List<Release> getReleases() {
        return releases;
    }

    public void setReleases(List<Release> releases) {
        this.releases = releases;
    }

    private List<Release> releases;

}
```

Release.java

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(namespace = "http://www.example.com/2023/08/31/releases")
public class Release {

    @XmlElement(name = "releaseName")
    private String releaseName;
    @XmlElement(name = "parentReleaseName")
    private String parentReleaseName;
    @XmlElement(name = "parentReleasePath")
    private String parentReleasePath;

    public String getReleaseName() {
        return releaseName;
    }

    public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
    }

    public String getParentReleaseName() {
        return parentReleaseName;
    }

    public void setParentReleaseName(String parentReleaseName) {
        this.parentReleaseName = parentReleaseName;
    }

    public String getParentReleasePath() {
        return parentReleasePath;
    }

    public void setParentReleasePath(String parentReleasePath) {
        this.parentReleasePath = parentReleasePath;
    }

}
```